# Find common elements from two lists (with PhoneNumberUtils.compare)

Tags: java, android, algorithm

So in this Android application, I have two lists with phone numbers in them. I want to find out common numbers in both. The brute force way is N^2. I can't use `HashSets` (I guess) because numbers can be in different formats. So my best bet is to use `PhoneNumberUtils.compare`. (It matches numbers of different formats. e.g. Returns true for "+91 9413294132" and "09413294132".

I want an efficient way as the lists are too large. One is my database and another is user's contacts. so basically I want to find out which numbers are registered in my database. (Maybe the same way WhatsApp finds out who is on WhatsApp). I'll really appreciate any effort. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to handle both lists in memory?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "the lists are too large"? A normal list with phone numbers would have roughly 500 contacts? 1000 contacts? By huge I understand atleast >1 000 000. Having an algorithm of N^2 for 2 lists of 500-1000 elements is not **that** bad

Comment: More or less... there´s a tricky thing accessing the context but u can handle, I think.` 
 private class MyNumber implements Comparable {
  String val;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
   return PhoneNumberUtils.compare(context, val, ((MyNumber)arg0).val) ? 0 : 1;
  }
  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Set<MyNumber> set1 = new HashSet<MyNumber>();
  //Fill the list!!
  
 }`

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes I can. I think the algo is efficient in memory and lists aren't **that** large. So there is no problem.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah. But I have to fetch list from database (that doesn't have to do anything with this, but the operations are being performed on same time. So user will have to wait for too long) And of course I'll be doing N^2 if there isn't a better way. I thought maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @VipulKumar If you have acces to both lists _in memory_, then you could go to O(n log n). First, sort both lists using a custom comparator that uses `PhoneNumberUtils.compare`. Second, run through both lists once comparing both current entries. As both lists are sorted, you always know which _pointer_ to advance if they do not match. First step is O(n log n). Second step is O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you're concerned about memory/time or both of them.

1. You're concerned about memory

   Go with the brute force N<sup>2</sup> solution because it uses no extra memory at all(only the memory required to keep the common elements), and     N<sup>2</sup> in practice is not that bad for small size lists. Anyway, fetching the phone numbers from database is more likely to cause a bigger performance hit than your N<sup>2</sup> algorithm.
2. You're concerned about time but you can use extra memory

   Wrap your phone numbers into a wrapper class, and add all the phone numbers from the 1st list to a `HashSet`. Then, iterate over your 2nd list and check if set is containing the wrapped phone number or not. This will guarantee you a O(m+k*n) time ( you have to iterate each list just once , and HastSet's contains method is a constant k - where k represents the average number of Strings having the same hashCode.) . This tends to O(n) because 2 and k(should be 1 because String's hashSet() collisions are quite rare) are constant factors which can be discarded.

   ```
   class PhoneNumber { 

        private final String val;

        public PhoneNumber(final String val){
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            return this.getVal().hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj){
            if (this == obj) {
              return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
              return false;
            }
            if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
              return false;
            }

            PhoneNumber other = (PhoneNumber )obj;
            return PhoneNumberUtils.compare(this.getVal(), other.getVal()) == 0;
        }

        public String getVal(){
           return this.val;
        }
   } 

   private Set<PhoneNumber> getCommonPhoneNumbers(List<String> dbPhoneNumbers , List<String> userPhoneNumbers){
       Set<PhoneNumber> common = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();

       Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();
       for(String s : userPhoneNumbers){
           phoneNumbers.add(new PhoneNumber(s));
       }

       for(String s : dbPhoneNumbers ){
           PhoneNumber phoneNo = new PhoneNumber(s);
           if(phoneNumbers.contains(phoneNo)){
               common.add(phoneNo);
           }
       }

       return common;
   }
   ```
3. You're concerned about both the memory and the time complexity.

   Sort the 2 lists by using a custom comparator based on `PhoneNumberUtils.compare(String,String)` (this should take O(n log n)) and then iterate over both of the lists at once ( O(min(m,n)) ):

   ```
     private static final Comparator<String> phoneNoComp = new Comparator<String>(){
         @Override
         public int compare(final String s1, final String s2) {
           return PhoneNumberUtils.compare(s1,s2);
         }
     };

     private Set<String> getCommonPhoneNumbers(final List<String> list1 , final List<String> list2){

         Set<String> common = new HashSet<String>();

         Collections.sort(list1, phoneNoComp);
         Collections.sort(list2, phoneNoComp);

         int size1 = list1.size();
         int size2 = list2.size();
         int i = 0, j = 0;

         while(i < size1 && j < size2){
             int comparison = PhoneNumberUtils.compare(list1.get(i) , list2.get(j));
             if( comparison == 0) { // found a common element.
                 common.add(list1.get(i));
                 i++;
                 j++;
             }
             else if(comparison == 1){
                 j++;
             }
             else{
                 i++;
             }
         }

         return common;
     }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. It was really helpful. You saved me a lot of time.... and memory ;)